# Android Emulator not connecting with localhost Apache

Tags: android, apache, connection, emulation

I am developing an app in Android, and the emulator is not connecting to my localhost.
I have researched the issue and found some ideas but nothing seems to be working.

Below is the code i have been using:,

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/YES_BUTTON.php");
httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

I have also tried a connection using "http://10.0.2.2:3128/YES_BUTTON.php";

The code would run a php file, but nothing happens, I have also checked the server access log and no connection was ever made with the Apache server from the emulator.

This is my first time building an app, and was wondering if there was something I haven't done, do I need to map the emulator port with the 3128 port on Apache, disable the firewall? I am developing the app on a laptop,with the Apache Server on the laptop also, so everything is being done on the same machine. Is there anything I havent done that needs to be done?

Comment: Is everytihng in order in your manifest? Also, there was a question earlier today about a similar issue, the result of which was that the emulator wouldn't make network connections when it was launched from Eclipse. Have you tried launching the emulator manually?

Comment: Hi Brian, I just launched the emulator manually and it didnt work, I'll check that the maanifest is ok, i gave the emulator internet permission in there already, I'll check if there is anything else I need to do, thanks for advice

Answer (score 2):

I bet you forgot to add the INTERNET permission :)

[INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)

Comment: I have given it internet connection, I included the below code in the manifest file:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> I think it might have something to do with the proxy settings on the emnulator, I tried running the emulator manually after adding "-http -proxy" in the Additional Emulator Command Line Options, but it is not working still

Comment: Just checked the Internet on the emulator and is working fine, so its something else that is not working, I think it has something to do with the proxy/router settings as the emulator does not communicate directly with the developement machine, even though the emulator is running on the developement machine, it goes through a firewall/router.